# How can I add the product sku to the PDP page?

Tags: magento-2.1, php

I would like to add the sku to the pdp page right above "Color". I have narrowed down my html template search to the file `vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/view/options/wrapper.phtml`

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2013-2017 Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
?>
<?php
$required = '';
if ($block->hasRequiredOptions()) {
    $required = ' data-hasrequired="' . __('* Required Fields') . '"';
}
?>
<div class="product-options-wrapper" id="product-options-wrapper"<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $required; ?>>
    <div class="fieldset" tabindex="0">
        <?php echo $block->getChildHtml('', true);?>
    </div>
</div>
```

I can not figure out though where $block-getChildHtml('', true); is grabbing the html from for me to edit that page?

**UPDATE**

The layout that this template is using is at `magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view.xml`. If I remove all of the child blocks (options.phtml, text.phtml, file.phtml etc.), nothing changes. However if I remove the parent block (product.info.options.wrapper) the content does go away. So it seems the content is coming from the parent and not the children somehow.

```
<block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="product.info.options.wrapper" as="product_options_wrapper" template="product/view/options/wrapper.phtml">
    <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options" name="product.info.options" as="product_options" template="product/view/options.phtml">
        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\DefaultType" as="default" template="product/view/options/type/default.phtml"/>
        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\Text" as="text" template="product/view/options/type/text.phtml"/>
        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\File" as="file" template="product/view/options/type/file.phtml"/>
        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\Select" as="select" template="product/view/options/type/select.phtml"/>
        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\Date" as="date" template="product/view/options/type/date.phtml"/>
    </block>
    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Calendar" name="html_calendar" as="html_calendar" template="Magento_Theme::js/calendar.phtml"/>
</block>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the option type, it uses one of the phtml files under

```
vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/view/options/type
```

or

```
 vendor/magento/module-configurable-product/view/frontend/templates/product/view/type/options/configurable.phtml
```

and to get the product sku just call

```
$block->getProduct()->getSku();
```

Comment: Hmmm I tried editing all of those files under type and they dont seem to have an effect on the pdp page there.

Comment: if the pdp is a configurable product then also try vendor/magento/module-configurable-product/view/frontend/templates/product/view/type/options/configurable.phtml. Answer updated.

Comment: Thanks for your help Niko. I tried checking that template as well and that template does not seem to be associated with this area. I updated my question to try and better illustrate whats happening. It looks like the getChildHtml is getting html from wrapper.phtml somehow, but the child blocks in there are not the ones populating it.

Comment: Seems like maybe I need to edit the file at `module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/view/form.phtml`, though this seems like a parent template that should not be altered.

Comment: Or maybe this is authored?